# How do i get results from a database table based on the id of another table in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am have a bit of an issue that I need some pointers on if someone can help me please.

I am using CodeIgniter and need to display the client name, job name and task for each row on the timesheet list daily times are editable in the list but the 3 fields above are static. Currently i display the id of the client, job and task that are stored in the timesheetEntries table but i need to display the correct names from the seperate tables in each row on the timesheet Entries.

In its current state it returns corretc results and works well apart from the linking to the other tables.

I am going out of my mind on this one as i can't find the solution and am now suffering from code blindness.

Many Thanks

Model

```
function getAllEntriesByTimesheet($id){
    $data = array();
    $options = array('timesheet_id' => $id);
    $Q = $this->db->get_where('timesheetEntries', $options);
    if ($Q->num_rows() > 0){
        foreach ($Q->result_array() as $row){
            $data[] = $row;
        }
    }
    $Q->free_result();    
    return $data; 
}
```

Controller

```
function id($id){
    $data['title'] = 'Timesheets';
    $data['entry'] = $this->timesheet_model->getAllEntriesByTimesheet($id);
    $data['sheet'] = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $data['header'] = 'default/header';
    $data['main'] = 'timesheet_view';
    $data['footer'] = 'default/footer';
    $data['timesheettab'] = 'current';
    $data['expensestab'] = '';
    $data['holidaytab'] = '';
    $data['admintab'] = '';
    $this->load->vars($data);
    $this->load->view('default/default_view');
}
```

View

```
$datestring = '%Y-%m-%d';
if (count($entry)){
    foreach ($entry as $key => $list){
        $dateNow = mdate($datestring);
        $entryId = $list['entry_id'];
        $sheet = $list['timesheet_id'];
        $clientId = $list['client_id'];
        $jobId = $list['job_id'];
        $taskId = $list['task_id'];
        $fridayHrs = $list['friday_hrs'];
        $saturdayHrs = $list['saturday_hrs'];
        $sundayHrs = $list['sunday_hrs'];
        $mondayHrs = $list['monday_hrs'];
        $tuesdayHrs = $list['tuesday_hrs'];
        $wednesdayHrs = $list['wednesday_hrs'];
        $thursdayHrs = $list['thursday_hrs'];
        echo '<tr>'
            .form_open('/timesheet/update_entry')
            .form_hidden('entry_id', $entryId)
            .form_hidden('timesheet_id', $sheet)
            .form_hidden('date_modified', $dateNow).
            '<td>'.$clientId.'</td>
            <td>'.$jobId.'</td>
            <td>'.$taskId.'</td>
            <td class="studio">'.form_input('monday_hrs', $mondayHrs).'</td>
            <td class="studio">'.form_input('tuesday_hrs', $tuesdayHrs).'</td>
            <td class="studio">'.form_input('wednesday_hrs', $wednesdayHrs).'</td>
            <td class="studio">'.form_input('thursday_hrs', $thursdayHrs).'</td>
            <td class="studio">'.form_input('friday_hrs', $fridayHrs).'</td>
            <td class="studio">'.form_input('saturday_hrs', $saturdayHrs).'</td>
            <td class="studio">'.form_input('sunday_hrs', $sundayHrs).'</td>
            <td class="icon">'.form_submit('', 'Update','class="update"').'</td>
            <td class="icon"><a href="/timesheet/edit_entry/'.$sheet.'/'.$entryId.'"><img src="/images/sitewide/edit.png" alt="Edit Entry" width="24" height="24" /></a></td>
            <td class="icon"><a href="/timesheet/delete_entry/'.$sheet.'/'.$entryId.'"><img src="/images/sitewide/delete.png" alt="Delete Entry" width="24" height="24" /></a></td>'
            .form_close()
            .'</form></tr>';    
    }
}
```

These are the database table schema for related tables

tasks

```
+------------------+-------------------+--------+------+----------+--------+
| Field            | Type              | Null   | Key  | Default  | Extra  |
+------------------+-------------------+--------+------+----------+--------+
| task_id          | int(4) unsigned   | NO     | PRI  | NULL     | AI     |
| task_name        | varchar(100)      | NO     |      | NULL     |        |
| task_type        | int(2)            | NO     |      | 2        |        |
| task_code        | varchar(10)       | NO     |      | NULL     |        |
+------------------+-------------------+--------+------+----------+--------+
```

clients

```
+------------------+-------------------+--------+------+----------+--------+
| Field            | Type              | Null   | Key  | Default  | Extra  |
+------------------+-------------------+--------+------+----------+--------+
| client_id        | int(4) unsigned   | NO     | PRI  | NULL     | AI     |
| client_name      | varchar(100)      | NO     |      | NULL     |        |
+------------------+-------------------+--------+------+----------+--------+
```

jobs

```
+------------------+-------------------+--------+------+----------+--------+
| Field            | Type              | Null   | Key  | Default  | Extra  |
+------------------+-------------------+--------+------+----------+--------+
| job_id           | int(6) unsigned   | NO     | PRI  | NULL     | AI     |
| job_number       | varchar(6)        | NO     |      | NULL     |        |
| client_id        | int(4)            | NO     |      | NULL     |        |
| job_name         | varchar(100)      | NO     |      | NULL     |        |
| create_date      | date              | NO     |      | NULL     |        |
| start_date       | date              | NO     |      | NULL     |        |
| account_handler  | varchar(4)        | NO     |      | NULL     |        |
| studio_resource  | varchar(4)        | NO     |      | NULL     |        |
| action           | varchar(50)       | NO     |      | NULL     |        |
| by_whom          | varchar(10)       | NO     |      | NULL     |        |
| deadline         | date              | NO     |      | NULL     |        |
| job_status       | varchar(50)       | NO     |      | NULL     |        |
+------------------+-------------------+--------+------+----------+--------+
```

timesheetEntries

```
+------------------+-------------------+--------+------+----------+--------+
| Field            | Type              | Null   | Key  | Default  | Extra  |
+------------------+-------------------+--------+------+----------+--------+
| entry_id         | int(10) unsigned  | NO     | PRI  | NULL     | AI     |
| user_id          | int(10)           | NO     |      | NULL     |        |
| timesheet_id     | int(5)            | NO     |      | NULL     |        |
| client_id        | int(4)            | NO     |      | NULL     |        |
| job_id           | int(4)            | NO     |      | NULL     |        |
| task_id          | int(2)            | NO     |      | NULL     |        |
| monday_hrs       | decimal(4,2)      | NO     |      | 0.00     |        |
| tuesday_hrs      | decimal(4,2)      | NO     |      | 0.00     |        |
| wednesday_hrs    | decimal(4,2)      | NO     |      | 0.00     |        |
| thursday_hrs     | decimal(4,2)      | NO     |      | 0.00     |        |
| friday_hrs       | decimal(4,2)      | NO     |      | 0.00     |        |
| saturday_hrs     | decimal(4,2)      | NO     |      | 0.00     |        |
| sunday_hrs       | decimal(4,2)      | NO     |      | 0.00     |        |
| total_hrs        | decimal(4,2)      | NO     |      | 0.00     |        |
| date_entered     | date              | NO     |      | 0.00     |        |
| date_modified    | date              | NO     |      | 0.00     |        |
+------------------+-------------------+--------+------+----------+--------+
```

**Solution**

Provided by András Rátz

Model

```
function getAllEntriesByTimesheet($id){
    $data = array();
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->join('tasks', 'tasks.task_id = timesheetEntries.task_id', 'left');
    $this->db->where('timesheetEntries.timesheet_id',$id);
    $Q = $this->db->get('timesheetEntries');
    if ($Q->num_rows() > 0){
        foreach ($Q->result_array() as $row){
            $data[] = $row;
        }
    }
    $Q->free_result();    
    return $data; 
}
```

the View need to have the variable

```
$taskId = $list['task_id'];
```

changed to

```
$taskId = $list['task_name'];
```

sorted thanks :)

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Also, table schemas would help immensely

Comment: I have tried numerous ways around this but nothing I try works, to be honest working with multiple tables is my weakness and some pointers would be very much apreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you didn't wrote the table names, here is an example. You need to change your model.

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('timesheetEntries');
$this->db->join('otherTable', 'otherTable.id = timesheetEntries.taskId', 'left');
$this->db->where('timesheetEntries.timesheet_id',$id);
$Q = $this->db->get();
```

In $this->db->get(), leave blank the get part, because with from, you already selected the table.
Without the exact table structure, it's hard to write the correct syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's just me, but this seems to be more geared toward the database side of things. Without knowing the database structure, it'd be hard to give much more than to suggest maybe creating a view within the database that gives you what you want and then query and return data from this view.

Comment: a view within the database? really?